# Checkbox inside Matrix broken after update

Tags: matrix, field-pack

I have a Field Pack Checkbox, with just a single option, inside a Matrix field.

I just updated to Matrix 2.5.10, Fieldpack 2.1.1 (from the outdated version), and EE 2.7.2.

The value of the checkbox inside the matrix field will no longer save. If I check the single checkbox, submit the entry, and then go back to edit the same entry, the box is no longer checked.

I currently can't edit any old entries in this channel because the value of the checkbox will be lost when the entry is submitted.

Any Field Pack Checkbox **not** inside of a Matrix still works fine. I have tried re-installing Matrix and Field Pack.

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally - you'll have to contact us at support@pixelandtonic.com, prefferrably with some CP credentials :)

Comment: Thanks Andris. I figured out that this was being caused by a conflict with another add-on (Category Field).

Comment: @Dylan Please move your "fix" into an answer and select it as correct. The more detail the better to help others if they have this issue.